# ASP.NET application on IIS dropping Static resources from memory

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.Net web application that is hosted on IIS (Windows 2012R2/ IIS 8.5). The application constantly keeps dropping Static resources (i.e., static classes/collections) from memory causing massive slowdowns on random requests.

This generally happens when the IIS worker Process memory crosses around 900Mb(on the development setup, total memory 4GB), and then drops to around 350Mb. The same happens on our production setup (16Gb memory and Application consume at most 1.9GB, then drops to 800Mb)

**Setup**:

- Windows 2012 R2
- IIS 8.5
- Target Framework: 4.7.2
- Platform Target: X64    (I forced it to `X64` from `Any CPU` to rule out
  32-bit memory limits).

**IIS setup:**

- .Net CLR version: 4.0
- Enable 32-Bit Applications: False
- Start Mode: Always Running
- Idle Time-out: 0
- Idle Time-out Action: Suspend
- Private Memory Limit : 0

So as you can see I have ruled out pretty much everything I could think of. Is there any reason for the constant drops? Isn't the .Net CLR supposed to keep static classes in memory and not drop them randomly? or am I missing something?

Comment: Constant drops, is it related to pools restarting?

Comment: I think IIS just close you `AppDomain` if there no requests for a while. Are you storing a lot of data in this static fields? Why do you store that a lot of data in static fields? If it is some sort of cache, why not to store it in redis (for example)?

Comment: @BugFinder No, I made sure that is not the case by enable logging for pool restarts. Also in that case the memory should drop to zero and not halve.

Comment: @Achilles _"Also in that case the memory should drop to zero and not halve"_ - only if you aren't leaking memory

Comment: @vasily.sib Yes, is it a custom cache that we implemented. IIS closing the APP domain is not the case either. I can trigger the drop by sending frequent request. I just don't know what causes the drop and there are no logs/windows events to give any hints

Comment: @vasily.sib Sure, but there should at least be a log entry for pool restarts? Since I specifically configured that.

Comment: Those voting the question off topic/close: Is there somewhere else I can post this? I post it here because it can be either .Net CLR or IIS that is responsible, I don't know which one it is.

Comment: @Achilles, I mean that static resource can only be released when whole `AppDomain` is going down. CLR will never drop any piece of data just for lulz (or there should be a `NullReferenceException` somewhere). You need a massive debugging/profiling here (or just use another normal and convenient caching mechanism)

Comment: @Achilles Sure your code is not at fault?

Comment: How can we reproduce this issue?

Comment: @PatrickHofman The code also has proper logging in place, so if anything goes wrong, it should `at least` log it. That is what is bugging me so much. I can't seem to find a reason for it.

Comment: @Achilles, as you said you have logging - can you please log [AppDomain.DomainUnload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.domainunload?view=netframework-4.8) events?

Comment: @vasily.sib The only events that appear there are if I try to recycle the pool manually or stop/recycle the pool. No other information there either.

Comment: @Achilles i forgot that `AppDomain.DomainUnload` is not triggered for default AppDomain. Can you log one more event please [AppDomain.ProcessExit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.processexit?view=netframework-4.8) ?

Answer (score 0):

You're right that the application pool should log restart events - but I note that you've not listed disabling restarts completely.

By default IIS configures it's app pools to recycle every 29 hours (1740 minutes), which means that it won't restart at the same time every day, but it will recycle. However it should perform an "overlapped recycle" by default, where it brings a new instance up before it shuts down the old one.

There are a couple of options that might help if this is caused by restart events:

1. Disable recycling by setting the "Regular Time Interval" to `0`.
2. Leave it enabled, but use the [Application Initialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-application-initialization) features to properly warm-up your application. This is part of IIS 8, and is a module you can install in 7.5.

You've already set your start mode to `Always Running`, but with the App Initialization module you can also [declare a page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/applicationinitialization/) that the server will request during start-up to warm up your application:

```
<system.webServer>
   <applicationInitialization
      doAppInitAfterRestart="true">
      <add initializationPage="/default.aspx" hostName="myhost"/>
   </applicationInitialization>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Thanks I have disabled that setting as well and the memory flush happens way too often. I can trigger it within a few minutes, so that shouldn't be case either.

Comment: App Pools will also recycle for other reasons - are you writing any files to disk within the application root - this can cause IIS to recompile the project, forcing a restart if you're not careful (we've seen this with log files, temp caches, etc. and the like - there are ways to increase this limit). Finally, are running in web garden mode - have you changed the "Maximum Worker Processes" from the default `1`? If so, you will be creating a new set of static variables as each thread spools up.

Comment: We do write log files to disk but they go to a complete separate path to avoid any interference. We are not running in a web garden mode at the moment for reasons of cache synchronization.